# Python - subprocess.Popen - ssh -t user@host 'service --status-all'

Tags: python, linux, ssh, subprocess, popen

I've read a bunch of examples but none of them work for this specific task.

Python code:

```
x = Popen(commands, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
print commands
stdout = x.stdout.read()
stderr = x.stderr.read()
print stdout, stderr
return stdout
```

Output:

```
[user@host]$ python helpers.py
['ssh', '-t', 'user@host', ' ', "'service --status-all'"]
 usage: ssh [-1246AaCfgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile]
           [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
           [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path]
           [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]
           [user@]hostname [command]
```

Why am i getting this error?
Using os.popen(...) it works, it executes at least but i can't retrieve the output of the remote command via the SSH tunnel.

Comment: The output suggests you didn't passed sufficient/correct parameters to the command.

Comment: Remove the blank space item, and remove the single quotes around the last parameter.

Comment: btw, are you using public key authentication? or password authentication?

Comment: Consider using `paramiko` / `fabric`.

Comment: unrelated: use `stdout, stderr = x.communicate()` instead of `stdout = x.stdout.read(); stderr = x.stderr.read()`. The latter may lead to a deadlock if `commands` generates enough output. An alternative is to use different threads to read stdout/stderr concurrently *or* use `select` or `fnctl` modules (Unix)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thx! Will take that into account for sure! Wouldn't `readline()` get ride of the deadlock? or is it simply that the buffer is filled to quickly in general? Because i'd imagine that `select` wouldn't solve the issue if it lies within the buffer, only that `read()` can't catch up quickly enough but then again `readline()` would solve the issue?

Comment: @Torxed: `stdout = x.stdout.read()` reads *all* stdout. It means that `stderr` is *not* read at all until all stdout is read. Therefore once the stderr pipe buffer is full; `commands` blocks while trying to write to stderr but nobody reads it (the parent is busy trying to read stdout) -- deadlock. `select` or multiple threads allow you to read from both stdout/stderr pipes concurrently thus avoiding the deadlock.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Fair enough, in this particular example i didn't redirect `stderr` and didn't make use of it. Normally i'll redirect via `.. stderr=STDOUT` or simply read it once in a while. But making use of select in this particular instance isn't a half bad idea :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think your commands list is wrong:

```
commands = ['ssh', '-t', 'user@host', "service --status-all"]
x = Popen(commands, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

Additionally, I don't think you should pass `shell=True` if you're going to pass a list to `Popen`.

e.g. either do this:

```
Popen('ls -l',shell=True)
```

or this:

```
Popen(['ls','-l'])
```

but not this:

```
Popen(['ls','-l'],shell=True)
```

Finally, there exists a convenience function for splitting a string into a list the same way your shell would:

```
import shlex
shlex.split("program -w ith -a 'quoted argument'")
```

will return:

```
['program', '-w', 'ith', '-a', 'quoted argument']
```

Comment: I love you!

I think i've tried EVERYTHING, except the combination of removing the ' and shell=True. I've tried them seperately which ended up in err, but removing both those two it worked.

(< pretend >)God(< /pretend >) i love how quick people answer here..

Comment: Oh, and not being rude to noob questions..
Because some of us get brain freezes even tho we've programmed Python for soon 10 years and not being picked at once it happens gives me hope in humanity :) So, if i could, i'd give you more points for a NICE good answer! (Can't mark your answer as the solution yet, 1min or so)

Comment: @mgilson Can you explain why it is necessary to break up a single command into every piece (space-delimited) to pass it like this? commands = ['ssh', '-t', 'user@host', "service --status-all"]

Comment: That's what the shell usually does for you.  In python, we're just being a little more explicit.  Of course, depending on the string, we can usually use `shlex.split` to split the string as the shell would for us if you'd rather.